# Can I record videos on iPhone 3G using AVFoundation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video-capture, avfoundation

Is it possible to record video on iphone 3g with ios 4.1 using AVFoundation?
I m able to record audio and can pick still image using AVFoundation but not able to record video.

Comment: Can the Photos.app shoot video?

Comment: NO... there is no video recording in iphone 3G however there is an app in appstore iCamcorder Lite to record video on 3G....

Comment: what format, framerate and resolution does it do?

Comment: How to find frame rate,resolution ? It does not support any kind of setting where user can set these things.however video quality is poor.

Comment: open one of its videos in quicktime on your mac and Get Information.

Comment: gives error while exporting... anyways y this info is required? AVFoundation does support video recording on 3G?? I tried AVCam project from apple docs even its not recording video but just audio and captures still images

Comment: Looks like the 3G can't encode h264. I guess that other app has its own encoder implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the [`AVFoundation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html) reference documentation its stated that

> You should typically use the
>   highest-level abstraction available
>   that allows you to perform the tasks
>   you want. For example:
>
> - If you simply want to play movies,    you can use the Media Player
>     Framework (MPMoviePlayerController or 
>     MPMoviePlayerViewController), or for
>     web-based media you could use a
>     UIWebView object.
> - To record video when you need only    minimal control over format, use the
>     UIKit framework
>     (UIImagePickerController).

Comment: I m taking about iphone 3G where you cant record video using UIImagePickerController.I am following AVFoundation docs also WWDC 2010 session 409.. n using this i m able record audio and pick still images as i have already said in question...

Answer (score 0):

As long as a device has a camera, you should be able to record using AVFoundation, check out the AVCam demo code from WWDC 2010 to see how you can do that.

Comment: see my comment on above answer... I have already followed WWDC 2010 session 409  and AVCamDemo but even AVCamDemo is not able to record video...please check it gives alert saying this video will contain only audio but no video